# FTP upload it completed

Tags: asp.net

I am building an application using Asp.net / c sharp. I was able to build the FTP functionality. As part of the user's requirement, I want to notify the user that upload has been successufly completed. Is there a way to know that a file has been successfully completed?

Thank you !!

Comment: Would be easier to give an answer if you gave an excerpt of how your uploading the file.  Depending on how your uploading the file, you maybe be able to use [FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

Comment: Give meh teh codez!!! Seriously, RTFM dude. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial to use that class ?

Comment: there are several examples in the documentation.